# If OnItemClickListener is an interface in Android, how can we create an object based on it?

Tags: android

I am using the following code from [this site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html):

```
// Create a message handling object as an anonymous class.
private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something in response to the click
    }
};

listView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

Now it says that:

> You can respond to click events on each item in an `AdapterView` by implementing the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` interface.

If `OnItemClickListener()` is an interface then how can we create its object as in above code? What is the concept behind that?

Comment: You should really read a bit about the java programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I get your question, but in your example above `mMessageClickedHandler` is the object, and the object implements the `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` method. If you are coming from a C++ world, there you would need to implement an `OnClickListener` subclass or the like as a separate entity, but in Java you can, as seen above, create an anonymous subclass (I hope that's the correct designation!) in inline code.

It's not a technique I personally like that much, but it's such a common Java idiom that I just go with the flow!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an object for a interface. Anonymous inner classes allow you to do the following, though:

```
public interface MyInterface {  
public void myMethod() ; 
}

MyInterface myIntfObj = new MyInterface() {  
    public void myMethod() {  

    }  
};  

myIntfObj.myMethod();
```

Comment: i think this is a satisfactory answer.. as here we are creating an inner class to the interface (which is allowed in java), and this class we are creating as an anonymous class, so basically its a new class that defines the method of interface..

Comment: yep.. the “inner class” that is implicitly implementing that interface providing the abstract definitions for the interface....:)