# is OnItemClickListener a nested class of AdapterView?

Tags: android

I am reading a book and the authors write `OnItemClickListener` is a nested class with `AdapterView` class.

Yet inside the `AdapterView` class `OnItemClickListener` is declared as a `public static interface`

The code in question is

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemclick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long id) {
          ...
     }
}
```

Are the authors right ?

## Edit:

This [If OnItemClickListener is an interface in Android, how can we create an object based on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602143/if-onitemclicklistener-is-an-interface-in-android-how-can-we-create-an-object-b) is asking the same question

The link provided in the original question by Amit Bhandari to the Android developers webpage (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) [scroll to the very bottom] says that the anonymous class itemClickListener is implementing the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `OnItemClickListener` class is defined within the `AdapterView` class (and you must call `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to use it), then it is indeed a nested class.

If it weren't a static class, it would be called an **inner class** by convention.

It is called an **interface** because it has purely virtual functions which are meant to be implemented by a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Hello user2923955 the authors are correct it is a nested class also called has parent class or super class

> Parameters
>
> **parent** - The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> **view** - The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view
> provided by the adapter)
>
> **position** - The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> **id** - The row id of the item that was clicked.

This are all definitions found on the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) of the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`:

> **Class Overview**
>
> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when
> an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

If i helped please up my answer :)

Comment: I would like to up any answer. However, I don't have the ability to do that until I ask more questions apparently.